# Responsive web problem on different browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive, microsoft-edge

I'm about making a responsive blogger template. I developed it in Chrome from scratch but when I opened it with other browser, in this case is Ms Edge and Internet Explorer, there's a little problem. When I resized the window to mobile size, the horizontal scroll shown. So I tried to open in Android Browser (not Chrome) on my phone, the horizontal scroll is gone. Is this from my code or Ms Edge itself?

**The horizontal scroll shown when the window resized**

[image: screen shot]

Comment: It's likely to be a case of differences in the browser rendering engines. But, to help, we need to see your [mcve] code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want hide only horizontal scroll, put this in your css:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a simple `body {overflow: hidden;}` to your css to block out the scroll.

Is it what you wanted ?

Comment: This will hide the vertical scroll too.

Comment: That's work but I can't scroll down event I pressed the PgDn button.